# How equal separate 3 div inside 1 div

Tags: html, css

I'm currently learning HTML. I'm trying to add 3 images inside a div, the images need to have the same amount of space between them. How to do this?

Example: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1WZdL0WVz-VndX2qP0Ig0S8fZnCGW2k37RHvWXLdgWz0/edit?usp=sharing

The code I currently have:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .maindiv{
    position: relative;
    width:90%;
    height:50%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:Red;
    border-width:2px;
  }

 .imgbott{
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    max-width:200px;
    max-height:200px;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>


<body>
  <div class="maindiv">
    <div class="imgbott">
      <img src="https://sites.google.com/a/itcld.com.br/portal-de-treinadores/_/rsrc/1377018552616/imagens/images.jpg" alt="">
      <a>TESTE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="imgbott">
      <img src="https://sites.google.com/a/itcld.com.br/portal-de-treinadores/_/rsrc/1377018552616/imagens/images.jpg" alt="">
      <a>TESTE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="imgbott">
      <img src="https://sites.google.com/a/itcld.com.br/portal-de-treinadores/_/rsrc/1377018552616/imagens/images.jpg" alt="">
      <a>TESTE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Code runing: https://script.google.com/a/macros/itcld.com.br/s/AKfycbyjeAIFhKnAXzvXd8lS3S-ND4H0n63i-FBxr-i9Z1omeFmBYtA/exec

Thank you.

Comment: Try this tutorial: [Perfectly justified CSS grid technique using inline-block](http://code.jelmerdemaat.nl/2012/perfectly-justified-css-grid-technique-using-inline-block/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to:

```
.imgbott{
    margin: 0px 10px;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    max-width:200px;
    max-height:200px;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The `margin: 0px 10px` means `0px` margin to the top and bottom, and `10px` margin to the left and right. Maybe one would expect `20px` margin between the divs then, but there is a effect called "margin collapsing" which prevents that.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you looking for
http://jsfiddle.net/Gfnjz/

```
.box {
display:table;
table-layout:fixed;
min-width:900px;         /* some minimum width is a good idea. */
border-spacing:20px 0;   /* note that spacing is also applied to right and left ends */
background-color:#666;
margin:0 auto;
 }
 .box div {
display:table-cell;
width:33%;
vertical-align:middle;
border:1px solid #bbb;
background-color:#eee;
padding:30px;
 }
```

Comment: I'd rather see a solution without `display:table`. Not just due to the feeling of semantic purism, but also because tables can't transition their size properly. I still like the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
.divName{
    width:300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Then for the last box, apply a .lastBox class as well to force no margin, that way they are perfectly centered, assuming your parent container is centered that is:

```
.lastBox{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="divName">
    <p>stuff</p>
</div>

<div class="divName">
    <p>stuff</p>
</div>

<div class="divName lastBox">
    <p>stuff</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want the same space between the "imgbott" divs, set their margin instead of width attribute.

Your class will looks like

```
.imgbott{
    margin: 0px 10px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.imgbott a 
{
    display:block;
}
```

Then doesn't matter what is the width of the images inside, the space will always be 20px between the images.

In additional you can remove the margin-left of the first image using the first-child selector

```
.imgbott:first-child {
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result by using `inline-block`s and `text-align: justify`, with adding some fake content before and after the divs to be aligned via pseudo-elements:

```
.maindiv{
    width:90%;
    border: 2px solid red;
    text-align: justify; /* turns on justification 'magic' */
    line-height: 0; /* removes extra space below divs because of extra line */
}
.maindiv:before {        
    font-size: .1px;
    content: 'i'; /* adds nearly invisible fake content in the beginning of the line */
}
.maindiv:after {    
    font-size: .1px;
    content: 'i i'; /* adds nearly invisible fake content in the of the line */
    word-spacing: 99in; /* huge word-spacing assures that the 2nd 'i' wraps to the next line making 'justify' work */
    background: #ccc;
}

.imgbott{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1; /* restore the normal line height inside divs */
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NwLz6/4/)

Optionally, you can prohibit the wrapping of the divs if the container is narrower than the sum of their widths by adding `white-space: nowrap` to the container and `normal` to its `:after`: see [edited JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NwLz6/5/)

This solution may look a bit tricky, but it works for arbitrary number of blocks of arbitrary (possibly different) widths.